# Getting cryptographically secure random numbers in C++ on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, security, random, cryptography

I'm working on an iOS app that is written in Objective-C and C++. In the C++ part, I need cryptographically secure random numbers.

1. As I understand the iOS security model, there is no way to access `/dev/random` directly. Is that correct?
2. The official way to get secure random numbers is [SecRandomCopyBytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecRandomCopyBytes). Sadly, this is an Objective-C interface. Is there a way to use this interface from C++, ideally without resorting to Objective-C++?

There's also [arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html), but I'm reluctant to use anything that's based on RC4 nowadays...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The official way to get secure random numbers is SecRandomCopyBytes. Sadly, this is an Objective-C interface. Is there a way to use this interface from C++, ideally without resorting to Objective-C++?

`SecRandomCopyBytes` is a C API. There is no problem using it from C++.

Here's a full example. No ObjC++ required, even using fancy `vector` and whatnot to show it's all C++. Obviously you could just use `malloc`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Security/Security.h>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const int length = 20;
    std::vector<uint8_t> randomBytes(length, 0);

    int rc = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, randomBytes.size(), &(randomBytes[0]));
    if (rc != 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed: " << rc << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < randomBytes.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::hex << +randomBytes[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One way to get cryptographically secure random numbers on any "C" based language including Swift is the "C" [arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) functions.

For random number integers (u_int32_t) use `arc4random()` and `arc4random_uniform()`.

For a range of random bytes use the `arc4random_buf()` function fills the buffer of length nbytes with ARC4-derived random data.

RC4 is a part of arc4random, the key is the continual seeding:

> The arc4random() function provides a high quality 32-bit pseudo-random number very quickly. arc4random() seeds itself on a regular basis from the kernel strong random number subsystem described in random(4).

The arc4random [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.4/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c) is available. Note that it is seeded by (stir) partially by reading from `/dev/urandom`. Care is taken to avoid well known RC4 weaknesses. Additionally the time is included when initializing the state making it impossible to regenerate the same random sequence twice.

Note: While the docs state that `/dev/random` blocks on lack of entropy this may not be true on OS X and it may be more like `/dev/urandom`.